# Error when parsing the group chat in telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a script for the documentation of pyrogram for parsing messages in public chats, but it either gives me an error, or does not give anything at all, here is the code:

```
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = 272347
api_hash = '235ausfhi...'
gruppa = 'xxx'

with Client('sessia1', api_id, api_hash) as app:
    spis_mas = []
    for message in app.iter_history(gruppa):
        spis_mas.append(message.text)
            
with open('spis_of_mes.txt', 'w') as file:
    for mem in spis_mas:
        file.write(str(mem) + '\n')
```

Here is the error:

> [sessia1] Sleeping for 26s (required by "channels.GetMessages")

Comment: is that the whole error?

Comment: yes, but I already seem to have almost figured it out.

Comment: no, I don't understand what the error is

Answer (score 0):

- That is not an Error -
  You cant get a all history with  `iter_history` in one time
  you should wait to `iter_history`  generator finish !